# How to find the extraneous attributes of functional dependency?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I have a relation `r(A,B,C,D,E,F)` satisfying:

```
AB->C
C->A
BC->D
ACD->B
BE->C
CE->FA
CF->BD
D->EF
```

I need to find the canonical cover for this relation?

I know the algorithm to find the canonical cover. However in the algorithm, we need to find the extraneous attributes. Is there an algorithm to find extraneous attributes?

Comment: What does your reference say about extraaneous attributes? What does googling give? Please google 'stackexchange homework' & read [ask] & the downvote down arrow mouseover text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [database refinement - minimal cover of F (extraneous attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008354/database-refinement-minimal-cover-of-f-extraneous-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm to find extraneous attributes is the following:

```
let F the initial set of functional dependencies
assume that each dependency F is in the form A1, A2, ..., An -> B
for each functional dependency A1, A2, ..., An -> B in F with n > 1
    for each Ai
      if B ∈ ({A1, A2, ..., An} - Ai)+ 
         then Ai is an extraneous attribute and must be removed from the left hand side
```

Note that the closure of the remaining attributes *must* be computed by considering *all* the dependencies of F, including the dependency under examination (this can be counterintuitive).

For instance, applying this algorithm to your example, starting from the dependencies:

```
{ A B → C
  A C D → B
  B C → D
  B E → C
  C → A
  C E → A
  C E → F
  C F → B
  C F → D
  D → E
  D → F }
```

In `A C D → B`, `A` is estraneous since `{C D}+ = (A B C D E F)`, while in `C E → A`, `E` is estraneous since `{C}+ = (A C)`.